# Game On! Schedule

Tags: discussion, game-on

**Game A**: <s>League of Legends</s> We need a replacement! LoL popularity has dwindled. Any suggestions?
**Game B**: Minecraft

**Fourth Week Games**: Diablo 3

Time: 1800 - 2115 UTC

**June 9:** ???
**June 10:** Minecraft: Capture the Wool

**June 16:** ???
**June 17:** Minecraft: Ultra-hardcore

**June 23:** ???
**June 24:** Minecraft: Mine Mayhem adventure map