# Game On! restructured

Tags: discussion, game-on

> #### Important Links:
>
> [**Schedule**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/game-on-schedule)
>   [**Server List**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/gaming-stack-exchange-server-list)
>   [**Game On! Chat Room**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on)

So, it's taken me awhile (due to school), but I've finally come up with the promised [restructuring of Game on!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/restructuring-game-on).The new structure I've decided on is a combination of badp's idea and my own.

**New Structure**

The new system will work on a four-week cycle. For three weeks, we will play **two main** games, **Game A**, and **Game B** every weekend. **Game A** will be played every **Saturday**, and **Game B** every **Sunday** (both at **1900 - 2215 UTC**). On the **fourth week two different games** will be chosen, and those will be played that weekend in place of the two main games. The four week cycle will then repeat itself.

**Game A and Game B**

Initially, Game A will be **Team Fortress 2** and Game B will be **Minecraft**. However, if there is enough support to switch out one of these games for another one, we can. Ideally we would do this at the start of a three week cycle, instead of in the middle of on, announcing the change a week or more before hand (so users know in advance a change has taken place.

**The Fourth Week**

The games played on the fourth week can be just about anything, although some restrictions will be placed. Obviously the games will need to have online multiplayer, but should also lend itself well to being played in a 3-hour time period. The games to be played on the Fourth week will be announced at the start of a new three week cycle.

**Where will the schedule be posted?**

The [Game on!](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on) chat room will be where the schedule will be posted the start of every cycle, and where any other announcements will be made.

I have also converted the [Game on! Schedule](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/game-on-schedule) question to feature the schedule for the current cycle. The following cycle will also be posted there, although it will only be posted a week or two in advance.

**Where can I suggest a game to be played?**

All game suggestions should be posted as answers to this question. Please limit yourself to one game per answer. Games will be chosen based on their score, so please make sure to vote on any games posted. However, if you down vote a game, please leave a comment indicating why. That way we know if it is simply because you dislike the game, if their is something about the game which makes it a bad fit for game on, et cetera.

**Organizers**

I'm looking for a few volunteers to help me organize Game on!. The main responsibility will be to make sure Game On! runs every week. The game to be played on the fourth week, and any changes to Game A and Game B, will also be decided by this group.

This section is somewhat vague, but that's because it's hard to say what exactly the organizers will be doing, it will depend on the game. For example, if we are playing a Minecraft adventure map, you would make sure that our Minecraft server is up and the map is uploaded.

If you would like to volunteer, please post it as a comment.

**Editors and Recorders**

I'm looking for volunteers to record some of our Game On! sessions. We won't be doing this for every session, only some of them. Some games simply don't lend themselves well to such a recording, and their is also the matter of the time it takes to edit and upload the video to YouTube.

With that said, I have no experience with video editing, nor do I have a program to record videos. Therefore I'll be looking for volunteers to record some of our Game On! sessions, edit them, and upload them to our YouTube channel.

If you would like to volunteer, please post it as an answer, and also include what you would be willing to do (record, edit, both, et cetera)

**Complaints**

**E-Mail:** [stackgaming`<AT SYMBOL>`gmail`<A DOT>`com](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=01b-lz92pBvxu4kM0WY3p6Gw==&c=YFBUVIdaQfpgsxvFths2AwsXeYmrZyIQk4te1wN6Ul4=)

If you have any complaints about any of the users please send use the above E-Mail to send us an E-Mail outlined with your complaints. We want this to be a good experience for everyone, so if any users are causing anyone problems we would like to know so we can talk to them about it.

**Questions, suggestions, complaints, volunteers, et cetera?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer relevant. If we revive game on, we should make a new post.

Answer (score 7):

**[Tankball 2](http://maidmarian.com/Tank.htm)**

It's a browser based game, completely free, easily accessible, and not very intensive, so it's easy to run. It does however, require Shockwave player (it's sort of old).

Up to four teams of any size scramble around a small island in nimble little vehicles shooting bouncing explosives at one another. With enough people, you end up with shots flying all over the place.

Yes, it may be sort of old. Yes, it may be a tad unpolished. Yes, it may not look the greatest. Yes, the controls may kind of suck. But it sure is a lot of chaotic fun when playing in a group.

It's free
It's gigantically accessible
It's easy to pick up and play
It's fun!

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

The great part is that by using the /join # command, we could all join our own game room (there are 99 to choose from). Maybe room 53 (SE, get it?), for example.

Answer (score 6):

Might I suggest **Left 4 Dead 2** at some point?

Comment: Really, either of the Left 4 Deads would work, but since ya wanted 1 per post, I picked one. lol

Answer (score 6):

Terraria would be a good one to try

Comment: I also like the idea of Terraria, but it'll require some special handling if we go for it. It'd probably be less fun if characters are at wildly differing power levels!

Comment: I guess it might be a bit hard going if we all create a new character from scratch...

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest [league of legends](http://leagueoflegends.com).

It's a online game for windows, you are a controller for a hero. It's very similar to Warcraft 3 heroes. but you can buy new heroes and if your hero die it will be revived in a matter of seconds. the goal is to destroy a structure on the other side of the map and two teams fight against each other. both teams have small bots to help fight with them, they are very small and do little damage.

You can buy more equipment and stuff during the game.

A game lasts between half and hour and 1.5 hours.

*This game is Windows only.*

Answer (score 3):

[King Arthur's Gold](http://kag2d.com/) is a team-driven sidescroller which may strike you as similar to Terraria at first, however, the games are much more structured, and it's free(mostly).  It's *loads* of fun.

Answer (score 3):

I found another interesting [Race for Wool](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/784749-rfwcollection-thungons-hidden-redemption-series/) series that we might want to try at some point if anyone is up for long games.

Answer (score 2):

I'll gladly record when I am able to make it - I've got PlayClaw and a fairly capable PC.  No idea how to edit anything though, someone might need to take over at that point.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest the **Sea of Flame** adventure map for Minecraft.

- It's made by the same person who has made all our previous maps so far.
- It's made for singleplayer, so we would all be on one team.
- When you find resources, you usually find a *lot* of them, (Cue Wipqozn; alot of resources) so we would be able to equip everyone, despite it being made for singleplayer.
- It's a "Find The Wool" style map, with ~15 pieces of wool that must be found.
- The treks for the wool take you through *amazing* terrain.

As the name might suggest, you start on an island in a sea of flame (lava).  But you don't stay there...

Answer (score 2):

How about a little [Scorched Earth](http://www.scorch2000.com/)? I somehow (still) [remember](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorched_Earth_%28computer_game%29) it.

Answer (score 1):

For recording TF2, it might be a good idea to petition whomever is hosting our server to set up a SourceTV bot and have it record demo files to disk.

A SourceTV demo recorded on the server side records the movements and activities of all players on the servers, as opposed to a client demo which just records the current player's viewpoint.  Someone may be able to use this to create a real video file, following the action as appropriate.

Replays are another version of this, but more limited.  Players can record replays of their previous life when dead by hitting F6, then later choose camera positions, etc... using the in-game editor.  You can see one replay I've done in my video 15 Backstabs in a Dead Man's Keep (which is one really long life):

Comment: I'll look into this for the following Game On! This one may be set it stone already

Answer (score 1):

Putting in the suggestion box http://omgpop.com/, A website full of multiplayer flash games like some kind of retro mario kart battles, no download needed. Just an account.

Answer (score 1):

[S4 League](http://mmohuts.com/review/s4-league) is supposed to be a *really awesome* third person multiplayer shooter.

Answer (score 1):

[Microvolts](http://www.microvolts.com/default.aspx) looks similar to Team Fortress, however, it doesn't *require* steam, and has a different, anime style.

Plus, it just released on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/109400/?snr=1_4_4__tab-NewReleasesFilteredDLC) for those of you who won't play anything not on the platform

Answer (score 1):

For retro stuff: [Goldeneye Source](http://www.moddb.com/mods/goldeneye-source)

Answer (score 1):

[Tribes:Ascend](https://account.hirezstudios.com/tribesascend/) It is a free FPS with a special movement system for a fast paced game on big maps.

Answer (score 0):

[Ball Land Battles Deluxe](http://sandbox.yoyogames.com/games/182308-ballland-battles-deluxe) might be interesting to look into, as it's free, and supports online play.  Some of the games you find in the Game Maker community are actually REALLY awesome, so give it a chance.

Answer (score 0):

[Alien Arena](http://red.planetarena.org/) looks like it might be a fun, and smoother alternative to Xonotic, since the turnout last time was pretty weak.

Answer (score 0):

[Robo Smasher](http://mmohuts.com/review/robo-smasher) looks like it might be pretty fun to play, even though it apparently has dead servers.

Answer (score -1):

[Cosmic Break](http://www.cosmicbreak.com/home) seems pretty awesome, if you're into giant robots and multiplayer.

Comment: I'm going to strongly recommend *against* this, due to a very sticky meta situation that has in turn produced a number of dangerous consequences (one of which is a community that ranges from downright hostile to simply uncaring of your lack of fun). It's a fun game, but it's not exactly the best of games for just playing once every week or two (and it's also not easy to get into the fold for playing consistently) - nevermind the money gap. So given the nature of how Game On operates, I expect the overall enjoyment of our participants to fall as time passes.

Comment: @GraceNote  Noted, thanks for the input.  Sounds like we'll stay away from this one.  =]

Answer (score -1):

I would want among us. It's suddenly become popular in Arqade, and it's great for groups. It is also good because you can keep spamming play again

Comment: Comment, please?