# Gaming Stack Exchange Server List

Tags: discussion, community

We have an increasing number of Gaming Stack Exchange servers for things ranging from Team Fortress 2 to Terraria. I've posted a community wiki answer to keep track of all the servers.

Use the following format:

**Game/Program**: *name of game/program*
**Address**: *server address*
**Password**: *password of the server, if it has one**
**Host**: *the user(s) hosting the server*
**Status**: *current status of the server. Is the server currently up or down?*
**Location**: *region/country the server is located*

---

Comment: I think that we should add, for each server, the country/region where it is located.

Comment: @Oak Agreed. I've modified the format to reflect this.

Comment: Just throwing the idea out for discussion: Should each server be in its own answer as a community wiki?

Comment: Might be worth linking the Steam Community Group as well

Answer (score 18):

**Game**: Minecraft (Feed The BeastDirewolf20 1.7.10 modpack)
**Address**: mc.echoreply.us
**Whitelist:** Ask TimPost or KevinvanderVelden [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk)
**Host**: [Tim Post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/224/tim-post)
**Status**: Up
**Location**: New York, USA

**Game:** Terraria
**Address:** thepugs.dyndns.org:7777 or terraria.stackgaming.com
**Password:** gseunicornsetc
**Host:** [Ian Pugsley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7816/ian-pugsley)
**Status:** Down
**Location**: Charlotte, NC, USA

---

Comment: @William I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but our host (@ThomasMcDonald) for the survival Minecraft server can be reached in our [Minecraft chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk).

Comment: Is the TF2 server active? I'm starting to get hooked again and it'd be awesome to stick to one server

Comment: @jmfsg: I don't think so, in fact I think Marco may have taken the server down (despite it saying it's up here)