# stackgaming.com DNS creation

Tags: discussion

I purchased and setup the http://stackgaming.com to make it easy for people to find and join community operated gaming servers. As [more and more](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/gaming-stack-exchange-server-list) appear I'd love to make this domain available to other users for DNS hosting. So, if you have a game server that you're running and would like a subdomain setup let me know! I'll eventually be building a front page which displays all the game servers available under the *.stackgaming.com domain

Comment: Just a thought, until you get a splash up and running, you might want to change the http://stackgaming.com URL to redirect to G.SE. It's a bit more friendly than doing what I did with [my domain.](http://www.lesspopmorefizz.com)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I wouldn't want to violate any [terms of use](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) by making it seem that stackgaming is masquerading as Stack Exchange Gaming. I'll have content up by the end of the weekend

Comment: I am an ametur web designer and am happy to help if you need any help with designing/implementing the website.

Comment: @William Thanks! I'll be uploading the source code soon for the site. At which point I'll really need volunteers to help maintain the code

Comment: OK! I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Just wondering, is this stuff still going on? Because @fredley's suggestions haven't been applied yet.

Comment: The DNS still points to servers, but seeing as how the Game On! events have gone to the way side I stopped working on the landing page.

Comment: Marco, I'd love to host a StackGaming SkyBlock server. If I would set that up (I run http://smallchunk.net), could you point sky.stackgaming.com to it?

Comment: @IanCarroll Certainly, just let me know the IP or hostname I should point that DNS record to

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Does the server have to be strictly for SE, or can I have it as a normal server?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Never mind, I'm going to fire up a special SE server. Could you point sky.stackgaming.com to 24.11.95.151 (think that's right, ping s1.smallchunk.net) It'll be on port 25565 once it's pointed and I fire it up

Comment: @IanCarroll DNS Created

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Cool. Also, I run http://serverbooks.net, a very small serverlist. Do you want me to deploy the code for the domain so we have a list of all stackgaming servers?

Comment: I'd like to host a TeamSpeak 3 server. Would you please set ts3.stackgaming.com as a CNAME to ts3.nightexcessive.us?

Comment: @NightExcessive DNS Created

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Is this website still being worked on? I would love to see what awesome stuff could be put on there :)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: I'm trying to go through and update our [server list](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3731/8350), and I was curious which of the servers you set up (if any) are still up. Would you mind going through the list, and removing the stackgaming.com servers which no longer exist?

Answer (score 11):

Can we point `stackgaming.com:80` to a useful page of information? A simple wiki of:

- A list of all `*.stackgaming.com` servers
- A list of events (Game On)
- Links to relevant meta-posts, YouTube videos, social media accounts etc.
- Links to other community-created content

It would be a useful place to advertise community events, and a handy landing page for all our community-related nonsense.

The reason I'd like to have this is that currently there's no way to find out everything that goes on on this site. We have a load of community-created content, from videos to Minecraft mods, but no central listing of where it all is.

I'm happy to host/administer the service if need be (I have *bags* of hosting capacity)

Comment: Just to outline how I'd choose to set this up: Probably Wordpress with a nice custom theme applied. That way we can provide a 'home page' of information that can be collaboratively edited, as well as a feed that grabs all updates from elsewhere (New YT vids, blog posts etc.) as well as announcements (New Foo server at `foo.stackgaming.com`). It would *not* be a blog. I don't have much experience with wikis but the one's I've looked at seem like overkill for what we need, and difficult to theme nicely.

Comment: This is actually in the works. I've just been busy working at work.

Comment: Great! Well as I said, I'm happy to help out.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea. Also, I've always wondered whether or not all of our Game On! and whatnot posts are actually appropriate for Meta or if we should stick them elsewhere, as they're technically not *about* the site itself. Though I do realize this is currently the only place for it and we do have Game On! chat, forums are usually a better structure for community stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

StackGaming was down for me yesterday and today serves up a page that says "Go away". Are you still doing anything with the domain?

Comment: There was an issue with my DNS servers that's since been repaired. For the record the site has always said "Go Away". It now redirects to this topic and all previous DNS records were restored.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Ah, fair enough. Would you mind adding a link to this post instead of (or along with :)) the "go away"?

Comment: The domain now redirects here :) I've been working on a site that will display the status and statistics for SE gamers on the *.stackgaming.com servers. Just need time to finish it

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Are you still planning to do that status thingy or is it long forgotten?

Comment: I agree, it's been a while.