# Stack Gaming sponsoring gaming personalities live-streaming new games

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Food for promotional thought:

Yesterday several prominent [E-sports people/gaming personalities live-streamed *Kingdoms of Amalur*](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=308033) which as far as I can tell was some sponsored thing by the devs/publishers.  Stuff was given away (graphics cards, games, shirts, etc) for publicity and people (don't know how many) watched.  Gamers that watch those sorts of live-streams are likely *heavily* interested in the game and/or *really* like the caster so will give our site some of their weight.

Sponsoring an entire thing like that is probably a bit much, but hopping on the bandwagon seems like a nice idea.  Throw in some of our shirts, sponsor some giveaways, buy ads (did they do ads?).  That said, I don't know anything about the expense of such a thing, but some more business-y SE person could try to find out.

While this "suffers" in the sense that we're focusing on a single game (as with the tournament question), the benefit is clear; glomming on to a huge publicity swell that pales in comparison to anything else.  This gives our site a tremendous push and fair chance (versus competing with existing communities) to get a critical mass for new games, those that will naturally have the most questions.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it @NickT- thank you for the awesome and constructive idea.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz here I was referring to jumping on the social-advertising bandwagon like in my link, not people live-streaming existing games.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz ping. Yes, email me.